# Tabs not respond after camera intent shows

Tags: android

I have SherlockFragmentActivity with two sherlockFragment Tab manages with TabListener.

In first fragment Tab I have a button that open ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent in order to capture a image from camera. When onActivityResult is called I receive the image correctly but if I tap on second tab this tab doesn't select, only selected if I tap over any editText in first Tab, in this case the Tab is selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I check that this situation only happen if I open inent with crop functionality, with this code: 'Intent intentCamara = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     intentCamara.putExtra("crop", "true");' If I comment this line, tabs works fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Eclipse IDE then try cleaning your project (Project-> Clean). Glitches like the above often clear up when you try this option.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the same issue after project clean... tabListener doesn't work after show camera intent, when I focussed on any control on fragment works again...